# How to set an specific character set?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm using Excel to send information to my MySQL database. That contains several 'Ø' character. My database is set to utf8_general_ci and the website to `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

When I use an text field to edit the database all 'Ø' characters are changed to '?' in the text field, how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: How are you reading the Excel file? Are you using a particular PHP/Excel library, or saving it as a CSV file? Or is the data correct in the database?

Comment: also my question: is the data correct in the database?

Comment: Data is send to the database correctly with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the mysql connection encoding? In php you do it with `mysql_set_charset("utf8")`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the database is correct, then you need to ensure that the connection between your php script and the database is also UTF-8 by issuing

In mysqli do

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

or in mysql do

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8")
```

And ensure that your html is also set to utf-8 by adding this tag to header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```